# Subtract a value from several arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I need to subtract a number from my numpy arrays. 
Let's say, we have two arrays and I need to subtract `10` from each of its elements.

```
a = numpy.array([10, 11, 23, 45])
b = numpy.array([55, 23, 54, 489, 45, 12])
```

To do that, I enter:

```
a - 10
b - 10
```

And I get the desired output, which is:

```
array([ 0,  1, 13, 35])
array([ 45,  13,  44, 479,  35,   2])
```

But, as I have lots of such arrays, I was wondering if it is possible to get the same result, for example by entering `(a,b)-10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.array([a,b]) - 10` will work.

Answer (score 2):

If you enter:

```
numpy.array((a, b)) - 10
```

You get the desired result:

```
array([[ 0  1 13 35], [ 45  13  44 479  35   2]], dtype=object)
```

`(a,b) - 10` doesn't work because mathematical operations only work element-by-element when operating on numpy arrays.  So, the solution, as above, is to put `a` and `b` into one numpy array.